# iOS app from data on a volusion website

Tags: html, ios, web, store, volusion

For a company, they want me to create an iOS app that works like their website, but it's on the app store.

They would like me to implement the store as well, so users can login/buy products within the app.

However they haven't created this website themselves. They used the Website Builder, Volusion, to create their website and store their data, along with their store implementation.

My questions are:

- How can I access their database? If I can't, is scraping their website the only way to get the data?
- How would I implement the store? Should I try reading the javascript in the page source? Or would that be illegal.  And is this even possible?  Or should I just have a UIWeb view with their website?

What approach would some of you take?  I'm lost.

Thanks

Comment: If they have a mobile web site and they are OK with that being the app, you can just wrap it using something like PhoneGap, Titanium, or a simple app consisting of a splash image, an activity indicator, and a UIWebView. If not, you're going to need some kind of read and write access not only to the database, but to the store system and the authentication mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

This is a awfully broad ranging question... but start here.
http://support.volusion.com/article/volusion-api-developer-wiki-documentation

You'll want to connect to the volusion API, but seems like a better answer would be to just find something that can be used in IOS development to wrap a web app and then make sure that they are using a responsive template for their volusion site.

Good Luck!